# Updating the Google Play leaderboard limits after publishing

Tags: android, google-play-services, leaderboard

We have incorrectly estimated the limits of what can be achieved in our game (yeah, I know!) and we have set a max limit to the leaderboard in order to reduce cheating. The problem now is that we have organized a competition and players are blowing the limit our of the water, but we cannot seem to be able to update the limits after publishing, we have contacted Google for this but it's going to take awhile before we get a reply, so anyone has faced this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try steps given in [editing a leaderboard](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards#editing_a_leaderboard):

1. Click the leaderboard in the **Leaderboards** tab of the Google Play Developer Console. You will see the same form you used when first [creating the leaderboard](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards#creating_a_leaderboard), and you will be able to edit any of the fields as you wish.
2. When you're done editing a leaderboard, click the **Save as draft** button.
3. The newly edited leaderboard will be in a "ready to test" stage, and you'll be able to test it out.
4. If it is working correctly, select **Republish** from the drop-down list, and this will republish your game, along with all your updated leaderboards, to the public. See [Testing and Publishing Game Changes](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/testpub).

However, use [Management API](https://developers.google.com/games/services/management/) to manage your games to address cheating and fix player accounts or if you need to reset values for these resources:

- achievements
- quests
- events
- turn-based match
- real-time room
- leaderboards metadata for the currently authenticated player or for
  all players